# Nested routes with parameters in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I got a lil problem with routing in my app. I got component *Playlists* where i choose playlist I want to play and after click on specific playlist, component *Player* is loaded. 
Path to *Playlists* looks like that:

```
/playlists/toplists?name=Top%20Lists
```

I would like to get path to *Player* like that:

```
/playlists/toplists?name=Top%20Lists/player/r63yd?title=Today%27s%20Top%20Hits
```

It's because i want need to get back from *Player* to *Playlists*, even when someone just paste the link to the *Player* into browser. My routing for playlists looks like that:

```
<Route path="/playlists/:name" component={Playlists />} />
```

And i dont know what to do to be able to routing from *Player* to *Playlists* with path params.

Comment: You use Router Links, right ? if you're using it, can you throw out the Link codes ? If I understand you correctly, you want the player component to be rendered when you click the playlist button, and you need to send props with the router url ?

Comment: when i'm using the player i need to have in my URL params which make me able to go back to playlist component which is dependent on the other one..

Comment: please add your `Router` code to the question... are you using `Switch`?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavLink, BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Playlists = ({ location, history }) => {
  // somehow get some params
  const data = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

  const buttonHandler = (i) => {
    history.push(`${location.pathname}/${i}?param=${data[i]}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <h3>Playlists</h3>
        {[...Array(5)].map((_, i) => (
            <button key={i} onClick={() => buttonHandler(i)}>
                {i}
            </button>
        ))}
     </div>
    );
  };

const Player = ({ location, match }) => {
  const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

  return (
    <div>
        <h3>Player</h3>
        <p>my id is: {match.params.id}</p>
        <p>my param from URL is: {query.get("param")}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <NavLink to="/playlists">Playlists</NavLink>
        <Route exact path="/playlists" component={Playlists} />
        <Route path="/playlists/:id" component={Player} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: But the Playlist component is rendered with some props from component before it. Playlist got the info about it in the URL, so i can't just set route to '/playlists'. That's the problem. When i'm into player, i need to have in the URL params which are  necessary to route back - to the playlist compo.

Comment: It should be sth like /playlists/playlists_params/player/player_params

Comment: Updated answer. For me params in url is a little bit old-school.  You can put any state from  Playlists to `location.state` of Player, when you pushing new route to history. With params in url it will be a bit more code.

Comment: Yes, i understand but when i pass params in location.state and then try to paste the URL of Player in a new tab i got undefined in location.state

Comment: Updated answer. Now Player gets 'param'  from URL